# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'measurement_prob'

Tags: python, attributeerror

```
def measurement_prob(self, measurement):
    prob = 1.0
    for i in range(len(landmarks_loc)):
        dist = sqrt((self.x - landmarks_loc[i][0]) ** 2 + (self.y - landmarks_loc[i][1]) ** 2)
        prob *= self.gauss_roz(dist, self.sense_noise, measurement[i])
    return prob
```

for t in range(T):
myrobot.move(0.1, 5.0)
Z = myrobot.sense()

```
p2 = []
w = []

for i in range(N):
    p2.append(p[i].move(0.1, 5.0))
p = p2


for i in range(N):
    w.append(p[i].measurement_prob(Z))
p3 = []
```

I have a huge problem with that task, the definition function is in class robot

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the error message:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'measurement_prob'

This happens when you call `p[i].measurement_prob(Z)` with `p[i]` being `None`.

Since (at this point) `p` is the same as `p2`, what you need to look at is what `p[i].move()` returns in the previous for-loop.